# INSERT statement has incorrect syntax near WHERE keyword. Why?

Tags: sql-server

What would be the update statement for all records `WHERE USID = 49`?

This is what I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESSES (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, PostCode) 
VALUES ('1A','2B', '3C') WHERE USID = 49;
```

But I'm getting an error *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword `WHERE`."* What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The use of a WHERE clause here doesn't make any sense, are you selecting those values from a table?  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: You would not insert when there is data -- I think you want update

Comment: @Hogan I think you are right! what would be the update statement for `USID = 49` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

`INSERT` is used when you want to *create new records* in a table. It appears that you do not actually want to add new records. If you want to *modify existing records*, use `UPDATE` instead:

```
UPDATE ADDRESSES
  SET AddressLine1 = '1A', AddressLine2 = '2B', PostCode = '3C'
 WHERE USID = 49;
```

**Explanation why `INSERT … WHERE` is invalid syntax:**

The purpose of a `WHERE` clause is to exclude all rows but those that meet the specified condition. When `INSERT`-ing, there is no need to look at any existing rows at all; you want to create *new* rows, and these are completely independent from any existing records. Therefore `INSERT` does not require `WHERE` clause. In fact it doesn't allow it because it wouldn't make any sense at all.

With `UPDATE`, on the other hand, a `WHERE` clause makes sense because you are dealing with existing rows, and you might not want to change *all* existing rows, but only a subset. The `WHERE` clause allows you to define the subset of rows that will be updated.

Comment: THANKS... WHAT WOULD BE THE T-SQL for this? I mean I want to perform the same query through C# and SQL Command

Comment: @envyM6 What do you mean?, this is the T-SQL code for it

Comment: Perhaps add an explanation to your answer *why* you are showing a solution with `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: @stakx - I guess I could try, but in the comment envy said he wanted an update.  That is why I wrote it.

Comment: @stakx because the op asked for it on a comment

Comment: @Hogan, Lamak: I know. But in the spirit of education, perhaps it should be pointed out that the [`INSERT` and `WHERE` aren't a very logical combination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513524/sql-server-query-insert-with-where-clause/27513606?noredirect=1#comment43457333_27513524). Explanations are always more valuable than mere "here is the correct code" answers. IMHO answers should empower askers to help themselves in the future instead of just helping them out right now. (Nevertheless: +1)

Comment: @stakx - I love your point but I fail.  I could not think of any way to explain the situation except to say when you want to change existing data you use update.  That is why I put it in a comment.  Please write an answer explaining why they can't be combined so I can vote for it.

Comment: @Hogan you are absolutely right, i would have spent hours trying to figure out a way to use `insert` statement with `where`

Comment: @stakx you are right as well. but being a novice I prefer both. Codes with explanation is the best solution. because understanding of logic with explanation is the easiest and fasted way...

Comment: @Hogan: You did not fail. [You came up with a better explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513524/insert-statement-has-incorrect-syntax-near-where-keyword-why/27513606?noredirect=1#comment43458014_27513606) than I possibly would have: Your explanation is very down-to-earth and super easy to understand… only it isn't actually contained in your answer! :)

Comment: @Hogan: I've attempted an explanation. Feel free to edit or rollback as you see fit.